# Network connection quickly disconnects when tethering to phone in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, tethering

I want to share my (Android) smartphone's data connection via USB tethering on Ubuntu 16.04.

But unfortunately when I connect the usb cable and select tethering after a few seconds my network connection disconnects!!!

I have to unplug and plug it again, but it only lasts for 10 seconds.

Everything is fine on Ubuntu 14.04.

I checked on two systems that use Ubuntu 16.04 and both have the same problem.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue yesterday (also referenced in [this earlier question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777945/usb-tethering-keeps-disconnecting)), and worked around it by disabling ModemManager via the command:

```
sudo systemctl disable ModemManager.service
```

My subsequent USB tethering sessions have been stable since then.  Not the most elegant solution, but works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am also currently going through the same problem.

From what I gather, Ubuntu now recognizes the USB tether to be a "mobile broadband" connection, so it stops the wired connection and converts it to a "mobile broadband" one, and from that point configures it to match your configurations.

The only issue is that mobile broadband doesn't work.  I've been trying to find any documentation to stop/delete/remove this feature/function of what they call mobile broadband and keep it working the way it used to.