# USB Tethering internet stops working

Tags: usb, tethering

I use mobile USB tethering to connect to the internet from my PC running Ubuntu.

When I connect the USB cable to my PC, it works for a short while and then disconnects and stops working.

What should I do?

Comment: Make sure your phone provider does not block USB tethering.

Comment: What model of phone are you using?

Comment: LG Q6+ it also work in windows but in ubuntu become disable after about 2 min

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/817023/815258 This answer worked for me using LG Q6 mobile phone