# USB tethering not working in 18.04 fresh install

Tags: 18.04, tethering

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 (gnome) on my laptop (dual boot with windows 10). I am not able to tether my phone (Moto G5S plus) to the laptop (some other phones work but not all others). Tethering has been turned on on the phone and works with other laptops (that have Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 installed.
I tried an ubuntu 16.04 live boot usb on the laptop. Tethering works there.

It would be good to know if this is a problem with drivers or something else and how can it be fixed.

I've included the lines from dmesg that were added after I tried to tether.

```
[  273.496487] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=22b8, 

idProduct=2e82
[  273.496492] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  273.496496] usb 1-1: Product: Moto G (5S) Plus
[  273.496499] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: motorola
[  273.496502] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: ZY3227KD5X
[  308.485368] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 8
[  308.912138] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  309.061446] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=22b8, idProduct=2e24
[  309.061448] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  309.061450] usb 1-1: Product: Moto G (5S) Plus
[  309.061451] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: motorola
[  309.061452] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: ZY3227KD5X
[  309.098517] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[  309.101645] rndis_host 1-1:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, RNDIS device, a2:ff:40:66:ec:f6
[  309.101716] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_host
[  309.112511] rndis_host 1-1:1.0 enp0s20f0u1: renamed from usb0
[  309.154818] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s20f0u1: link is not ready
[  309.224187] rndis_host 1-1:1.0 enp0s20f0u1: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:14.0-1, RNDIS device
[  309.252183] rndis_host 1-1:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, RNDIS device, b2:4f:9e:67:b6:21
[  309.255446] rndis_host 1-1:1.0 enp0s20f0u1: renamed from usb0
[  364.510528] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  364.510534] NETDEV WATCHDOG: enp0s20f0u1 (rndis_host): transmit queue 0 timed out
[  364.510567] WARNING: CPU: 5 PID: 0 at /build/linux-lZKWha/linux-4.15.0/net/sched/sch_generic.c:323 dev_watchdog+0x221/0x230
[  364.510569] Modules linked in: rndis_host cdc_ether usbnet ccm thunderbolt rfcomm snd_hda_codec_hdmi nouveau bnep ttm snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 hid_multitouch dell_smbios_wmi dell_wmi mxm_wmi wmi_bmof intel_wmi_thunderbolt dell_wmi_descriptor arc4 snd_hda_intel dell_laptop dell_smbios_smm snd_hda_codec dell_smbios snd_hda_core intel_rapl dcdbas snd_hwdep x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp dell_smm_hwmon kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel iwlmvm pcbc mac80211 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi aesni_intel snd_seq_midi_event aes_x86_64 crypto_simd snd_rawmidi glue_helper cryptd intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf snd_seq iwlwifi joydev snd_seq_device uvcvideo snd_timer videobuf2_vmalloc btusb input_leds btrtl videobuf2_memops cfg80211 btbcm
[  364.510654]  serio_raw videobuf2_v4l2 btintel idma64 videobuf2_core snd virt_dma bluetooth soundcore videodev media cdc_acm mei_me intel_lpss_pci processor_thermal_device ecdh_generic mei intel_pch_thermal intel_lpss shpchp intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal wmi int3402_thermal mac_hid int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_pad tpm_crb acpi_thermal_rel sparse_keymap sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea nvme sysfillrect sysimgblt psmouse fb_sys_fops r8169 drm nvme_core ahci mii libahci i2c_hid hid video
[  364.510729] CPU: 5 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/5 Tainted: G        W        4.15.0-22-generic #24-Ubuntu
[  364.510732] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 7577/0J8HMF, BIOS 1.4.2 01/25/2018
[  364.510736] RIP: 0010:dev_watchdog+0x221/0x230
[  364.510739] RSP: 0018:ffff918ecf543e58 EFLAGS: 00010286
[  364.510742] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000006
[  364.510745] RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000092 RDI: ffff918ecf556490
[  364.510747] RBP: ffff918ecf543e88 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 00000000000005bc
[  364.510749] R10: ffff918ecf543ee0 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000001
[  364.510751] R13: ffff918eb7082000 R14: ffff918eb7082478 R15: ffff918eb489c680
[  364.510754] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff918ecf540000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  364.510757] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  364.510760] CR2: 00007f1de2989350 CR3: 000000040c80a003 CR4: 00000000003606e0
[  364.510762] Call Trace:
[  364.510765]  <IRQ>
[  364.510772]  ? dev_deactivate_queue.constprop.33+0x60/0x60
[  364.510780]  call_timer_fn+0x30/0x130
[  364.510786]  run_timer_softirq+0x3fb/0x450
[  364.510791]  ? ktime_get+0x43/0xa0
[  364.510798]  ? lapic_next_deadline+0x26/0x30
[  364.510805]  __do_softirq+0xdf/0x2b2
[  364.510811]  irq_exit+0xb6/0xc0
[  364.510816]  smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x71/0x130
[  364.510822]  apic_timer_interrupt+0x84/0x90
[  364.510824]  </IRQ>
[  364.510830] RIP: 0010:cpuidle_enter_state+0xa7/0x2f0
[  364.510833] RSP: 0018:ffffb92f0196fe68 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff11
[  364.510837] RAX: ffff918ecf562880 RBX: 00000054de84efcb RCX: 000000000000001f
[  364.510839] RDX: 00000054de84efcb RSI: fffffffddb4d39f5 RDI: 0000000000000000
[  364.510841] RBP: ffffb92f0196fea8 R08: 0000000000002e70 R09: 00000000000000c8
[  364.510843] R10: ffffb92f0196fe38 R11: 000000000000061a R12: ffff918ecf56cb00
[  364.510845] R13: 0000000000000004 R14: ffffffff98771db8 R15: 0000000000000000
[  364.510852]  ? cpuidle_enter_state+0x97/0x2f0
[  364.510858]  cpuidle_enter+0x17/0x20
[  364.510864]  call_cpuidle+0x23/0x40
[  364.510868]  do_idle+0x18c/0x1f0
[  364.510874]  cpu_startup_entry+0x73/0x80
[  364.510878]  start_secondary+0x1a6/0x200
[  364.510884]  secondary_startup_64+0xa5/0xb0
[  364.510887] Code: 38 00 49 63 4e e8 eb 92 4c 89 ef c6 05 28 56 d9 00 01 e8 23 38 fd ff 89 d9 48 89 c2 4c 89 ee 48 c7 c7 a0 73 39 98 e8 2f 04 81 ff <0f> 0b eb c0 90 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 
[  364.510966] ---[ end trace cd363f8d000b7ca4 ]---
```

Below is the result of sudo lshw -C network

```
    *-network                 
           description: Ethernet interface
           product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
           logical name: enp59s0
           version: 15
           serial: 54:bf:64:09:1c:e2
           size: 10Mbit/s
           capacity: 1Gbit/s
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
           configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
           resources: irq:129 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:dd304000-dd304fff memory:dd300000-dd303fff
      *-network
           description: Wireless interface
           product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:3c:00.0
           logical name: wlp60s0
           version: 78
           serial: 34:41:5d:5c:47:0c
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
       logical name: enp59s0
       version: 15
       serial: 54:bf:64:09:1c:e2
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:129 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:dd304000-dd304fff memory:dd300000-dd303fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3c:00.0
       logical name: wlp60s0
       version: 78
       serial: 34:41:5d:5c:47:0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-22-generic firmware=34.0.1 ip=192.168.1.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:138 memory:dd200000-dd201fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enp0s20f0u1
       serial: 3e:2a:f0:fa:ff:0d
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device link=yes multicast=yes
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-22-generic firmware=34.0.1 ip=192.168.1.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
           resources: irq:138 memory:dd200000-dd201fff
      *-network
           description: Ethernet interface
           physical id: 2
           logical name: enp0s20f0u1
           serial: 3e:2a:f0:fa:ff:0d
           capabilities: ethernet physical
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device link=yes multicast=yes
```

Comment: How did you end up solving the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Changing MAC address will Solve the Problem.

First Run:

```
ip link show
```

This will list the network devices,
Find the one you want to change.

For above problem device is `enp0s20f0u1`

Next Run:

```
sudo ip link set dev <your_device> down
```

Then:

```
sudo ip link set dev <your_device> address <your_new_mac_address>
```

or

If you want to generate random MAC address

Install Macchanger by running

```
sudo apt install macchanger
```

To change MAC address

```
sudo macchanger -r <your_device>
```

Finally:

```
sudo ip link set dev <your_device> up
```

Comment: I don't see, why this should help.

Comment: Change MAC on what interface? Wifi? Physical? tun-easyteather? loopback? Please define, "find the one you want to change"

Comment: @Enno Gröper, from what i observed, the MAC of the interface was resetting to 00:00:00:00:00:00, because of this we need to set the MAC of interface manually.

Comment: @David Parks, Change MAC of listed physical interface of mobile device

Answer (score 3):

I was able to usb tether after I enabled usb debugging on my phone. This was not required for any System I've used until now, hence I am not use why this was required.

Comment: I also faced this issue after a fresh install of **Ubuntu 18.04**.

I made **USB tethering** work after enabling **USB debugging** on my Samsung phone.

Comment: This worked for me (Motorola G7 plus, Android 9). Thanks! If USB debugging is disabled, I don't get an answer from the DHCP server on the phone. After enabling USB debugging, I get an answer. Reproduced several times.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling USB debugging (OnePlus 3) on Ubuntu 18.04 still didn't work for me, but I solved it by deleting the MAC address in network profile.

These are my steps (After enabling USB tethering):

- Open Settings, Go to network settings (on Ubuntu 18.04)
- Under USB ethernet group profile, open settings (gear icon) on your "auto" profile
- Select Identity Tab
- Delete or clear available MAC Address, leave it blank
- Apply changes

> It works, without enabling USB debugging

Comment: Didn't work for me :-(

Comment: This helps, because sometimes the mac address of the tethering adapter changes. Additionally I had to enable USB debugging. The latter seems to be dependant on the mobile phone used.

Answer (score 1):

I also have Moto G5 plus I couldn't tether. Looks like there is a conflict with ModemManager: [USB Tethering keeps disconnecting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777945/usb-tethering-keeps-disconnecting). I disabled and stopped it and it worked for me.

```
sudo systemctl stop ModemManager.service
sudo systemctl disable ModemManager.service
```

Comment: I saw crashes using dmesg, when trying to connect using my Motorola G7. Stopping ModemManager seems to avoid those crashes. Additionally I had to enable USB debugging to make USB-Tethering work.

Comment: USB-Tethering seems to work now with ModemManager enabled. No more crashes. :-\ Not sure this is really needed.

Answer (score 0):

For me Android 9 Miui 10

```
1) usb debugging turns on
2) Connect to computer and choose Transfer files (MTP)
3) next turns on usb tethering
```

let me know if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [supranov's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1082816/956640) above , I also had to assign a MAC address to my phone.

Using Ubuntu 18.04 with a Samsung Galaxy S7:

ifconfig -a

#find device ID for android: enp1a4O40v9 (enpXXXXXXXX)

sudo apt install macchanger
sudo macchanger -r enp1a4O40v9  # the -r means "random"

Answer (score 0):

1. turn on USB-debugging on your phone setting and test
2. turn off computer and turn off mobile device
3. turn on both and try again

for me restarting mobile and pc helped.