# Ubuntu 18.04 will not connect to Android Hot Spot, knocks out other land based connections

Tags: 18.04, phone, tethering

Tower computer, Quad core, Ubuntu fresh full install of version 18.04. Wifi antenna USB 2.4GHz & 5.0GHz high gain. (No laptop involved). Android phone set up as a Wifi Hot Spot with Data connection 'On'.

Issue: Antenna picks up wifi signal transmitted by phone set for hot spot just fine. But Ubuntu will not connect to the internet. 'Connection Failed. Activation of network connection failed'.

My other machine with Win7 connects to the phone and internet fine.

Once I try to connect to the phone and get the error message above, that knocks out the previously working wifi connection to my main land based wifi signal. Still see the AP it just will no longer connect. I have to reboot the machine to restore usage of my primary land based wifi connection.

Something in 18.04 is blocking connection to the internet through the phone. When this equipment setup was Ubuntu 16.04 it did fine connecting to the phone and internet many times over many months and many different locations (I travel extensively). So it's not an equipment issue.

I followed the advice in this thread but nothing there helped, plus it doesn't mention that just trying to use as a hot spot causes a working connection to fail and require a reboot: [USB Tethering not working...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043368/usb-tethering-not-working-in-18-04-fresh-install)

Any fresh ideas? 18.04 is over a year old, someone must have solved this issue by now. Right?

Thanks for any help as I use my phone tethered all the time and need it to work reliably.