# Unable to use USB Tethering in Jetson Nano

Tags: networking, 18.04, usb, tethering, nmcli

I have a Jetson nano that is running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I need internet access on the jetson. Currently, the only internet connection that I have is on my phone. I tried to tether my phone to the jetson via USB, but I cannot get internet access  to the device. Jetson recognized my phone as a tethered device. `lsusb` gives the following output:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04e8:6864 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9070 (network tethering, USB debugging enabled)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`ifconfig` gives the following output:

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:04:4b:e6:42:ac  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 19330  bytes 1209624 (1.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19212  bytes 1481427 (1.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 151  base 0xe000  

l4tbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.55.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.55.255
        inet6 fe80::6471:96ff:fe32:1cb1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 66:71:96:32:1c:b1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1047  bytes 141242 (141.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1665  bytes 1000956 (1.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3055  bytes 210875 (210.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3055  bytes 210875 (210.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

rndis0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::6471:96ff:fe32:1cb1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 66:71:96:32:1c:b1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 833  bytes 99622 (99.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1916  bytes 1158072 (1.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::6471:96ff:fe32:1cb3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 66:71:96:32:1c:b3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 238  bytes 44968 (44.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 167  bytes 37064 (37.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 1a:ac:23:09:50:8a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 2  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 58  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`nmcli` gives:

```
l4tbr0: connected to l4tbr0
        "l4tbr0"
        bridge, 66:71:96:32:1C:B1, sw, mtu 1500
        inet4 192.168.55.1/24
        route4 192.168.55.0/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
        route4 169.254.0.0/16
        inet6 fe80::6471:96ff:fe32:1cb1/64
        route6 ff00::/8
        route6 fe80::/64

usb1: disconnected
        "SAMSUNG Android"
        1 connection available
        ethernet (rndis_host), 1A:AC:23:09:50:8A, hw, mtu 1500

eth0: unavailable
        "Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller"
        ethernet (r8168), 00:04:4B:E6:42:AC, hw, mtu 1500

dummy0: unmanaged
        "dummy0"
        dummy, 76:23:BF:62:AC:13, sw, mtu 1500
```

Currently I have connected my laptop to the Jetson device via the micro-USB port on the Jetson.

Comment: Might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043368/usb-tethering-not-working-in-18-04-fresh-install

Comment: I would problem solve the phone first. I have not had a Samsung for a few years but the phone (or tablet) does not likle to tether when the WiFi is also enabled. So assuming you intend to use your phone's actual internet connection, try switching off the WiFi and internet sharing first, then USB connect the phone, then activate USB tethering and see of you get a different result.